# Xcode scroll on buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, scroll, touch

I have a scrollview in my app, in the scrollview there is a lot of buttons without any space between them... When I run the app, I can't scroll because I "of course" have to touch a button first, and ehen I try to scroll, the button that I touched gets highlighted, and when I release.. The button is pressed! So I can't reach the buttons that is further down in the scrollview!

All button has the setting "Touch up inside"..

I guess it is kinda easy to fix, but I don't know how! :P

/Noob

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property `canCancelContentTouches` on the `UIScrollView` to `YES` should allow it to cancel the touch event already sent to the button once it detects a scroll. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I wrote this line: [overscroll canCancelContentTouches:YES];

But I get this error: No visible (at)interface for 'UIScrollView' declares the selector canCancelContentTouches.

What do I do wrong

Comment: It's a property, so you should use the following code to set it: `overscroll.canCancelContentTouches = YES;`

Comment: I tried overscroll.canCancelContentTouches = YES; but it is not working! :O 
I get a warning that says that the property cancancelcontenttouches requiers method cancancelcontenttouches to be defined!
what code should I add then? :O

Comment: I also wrote this in the .h file:
@property(nonatomic) BOOL canCancelContentTouches

Answer (score 0):

You can do what ksoderstrom said or you can auto scroll using this method for your scrolview

```
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
```

textField can be a UIButton as well. This method will just move the scrollView to whatever component you specify.

Hoep it helps.

Comment: You can put this on any type of action. Maybe only the bottom at the end of the screen?

Comment: so I only have to do it once in the scroll view, and set it in one of the buttons?

 Or maybe you can help me with ksoderstroms comment? I wrote the error I got when trying it, below his comment!

Comment: If you post the rest of your code. What you wrote for canCancelContentTouches seems right

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i found out that it's really hard to test it in the simulator. When the code run on the actual device, the scroll view was working as it was supposed to...

Comment: Without any extra code? Cuz now it dosn't cancel the touch, even tho im using the cancanceltouch this!